# Mdriven attribute.type explanations

Tags: uml, modeling, mdriven

I'm new to coding and the program MDriven. I've got some quite basic questions on MDriven that I haven't found clear answers for.

Where can I find more detailed explanations for different attribute.type? For example: What's the difference between Guid and AutoGuid?

Comment: Presumably in the Mdriven website's official documentation. I've never heard the term 'autoguid' before, but I'd **assume** that it would be an auto-incrementing primary key.

Comment: I also never heard about that, but presumably you should read https://www.capableobjects.com/products/mdriven-the-book/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PersistenceMapping - how things are represented in a database - AutoGuid represents an dbgenerated Guid value.

As you state that you are new to MDriven, you will probably not be interested in overridden persistence mapping just yet → forget about AutoGuid for now.

Common types for attributes are the simple native types:

- String (size limited in the database)
- Text (text in database - no size limit)
- Double
- Decimal
- Integer
- DateTime
- Boolean
- Blob (Binary data byte[] -combine with setting for BlobType) Guid